# Gmapping and Navigation Stack

Tags: navigation, ros-indigo, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can Gmapping alongside with Nav Stack be used for navigating the robot while avoiding obstacles?
If so, is there any source code that can make life easier?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286125/gmapping-and-navigation-stack/) by [denisolt](https://answers.ros.org/users/33805/denisolt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-03-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you can do this -- Gmapping basically replaces AMCL (you should not run both at the same time, it will seriously mess with your TF). As for "source code" -- it's really a series of launch file changes (remove the amcl node, add gmapping), which will depend entirely on the robot you are using.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2018-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0